# What's the significance of the "One Week Later" font faces?

Tags: black-mirror

In *Black Mirror* season 3's *San Junipero*, the cuts between scenes feature the text

> ONE WEEK LATER

In a variety of fonts. I'm guessing they relate to the upcoming eras, somehow, but I don't know enough about typography to research if they're fonts of those times, or just styled after type of that era.

What's the significance of these fonts (real world/behind-the-scenes) in their relationship to the story or the time(s) the story is set in?

First (and second):
[image]
Before 1979/1980 scene:
[image]
Before 1996 scene:
[image]
Before 2002 scene:
[image]

None of these absolutely scream that "era" to me, although the 80s font comes closest.

Comment: Err, they *mirror* the eras they're set in? 1980s style fonts for the 1980s, more contemporary fonts for later times...

Comment: @Valorum But certain fonts are well-known/immediately recognizable to typographers that could say "Oh, that was Georgia, released in 1996, the year this scene is set in." for example.

Comment: @CreationEdge - https://www.reddit.com/r/blackmirror/comments/58zdc1/did_you_notice_this_obsessive_attention_to/

Comment: @JohnP Yeah, that was out way back when. There's not been any new findings on it. After the glow of the episode faded, no one looked back, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

#### First (and second):

[image: Normal font saying "one week later"]

I don't think this one has any significance. Probably chosen to be visually different from the others. Also the only one italicized.

#### Before 1979/1980 scene:

[image: 80s font saying "one week later"]

This font is very reminiscent of 80's arcades. Specifically Atari and games such as Asteroids or Battlezone. You can view a tribute font called *[Hyperspace](https://www.dafont.com/hyperspace.font)* that attempted (fairly well in my opinion) to recreated the Atari font face. This font is characterized as being all lines, as that was (presumably) easier to render on screens back then.

#### Before 1996 scene:

[image: 90s font saying "one week later"]

I can't identify this font. It looks like an altered version of *Foundation Sans*, but I have no idea why that would evoke mid-90s. It seems familiar. Maybe it was a common look on tv news or something. But I can't find any reason to think that to be true.

#### Before 2002 scene:

[image: 00s font saying "one week later"]

This one is almost certainly *American Typewriter* which was a font created in the 70s that evoked a style similar to typewriters, but unlike typewriters, was not monospace. While I don't have a source saying "this font was popular in early 2000s",  it does have a post-Y2K feel. I recall seeing it quite a bit in various places during that time; typically for a subtitle type text, or other such things that needed contrast from the main text. Also the History Channel really liked this font for some reason.

#### In summary

They appear to have had a strong correlation in their 80s font but then shifted to more vague references for the following two decades. This is understandable due to the fact that personal computers started taking off right around then, and so the number of fonts available skyrocketed. This meant that there was not a single font that dominated the scene (think 40s propaganda posters or 50s culture). Instead we had a bunch of fonts that looked similar (or completely different... wingdings...). The bold, blocky, lowercase of the 90's font is appropriate (in my opinion), but relies heavily on context for it to be understood. The same goes for the 00's font. If you showed it to me, my first thought would be the documentaries of my childhood and teen years. Which is adequate, but does not work alone.

I have not been able to find any word from the creators on this subject, but many online reviews of the episode seem to find the font choice satisfactory. So while we may not know for certain why these specific fonts are significant, the point was definitely to evoke the typography of the specific eras, and based on reception, seems to have accomplished that goal.

---

<sub>I recognize this is a poor answer and a very long winded way of saying "we don't know specifically". However, in my experience and research (neither of which is insignificant), it really is vague enough to not have a good answer short of WoG or a degree in design/typography. I welcome anyone else to use this answer as a starting point for their own if they can add something more substantial.</sub>

Comment: I was hoping for a typography nerd to have an answer, if anyone, yeah.